# Unable to select item name in DropDownList on selectedindex_changed event?

Tags: asp.net

Code in Page_Load() event is as follows :-

```
    SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(conn);
    c.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = c;
    cmd.CommandText = "select name from Employee1";
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(dr["name"].ToString());
         }
    }
```

Code in DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged() event is as follows:-

```
Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

I also tried writing

```
Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem;
```

I wan't to use that name in following query

```
cmd.CommandText = "select salary from Employee1 where name='"
                     +DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text+"' ";
```

Comment: dropDown.SelectedValue?

Answer (score 0):

Use if `!Page.IsPostback` to bind the data.

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
 {
    //bind your dropdown here
    SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(conn);
    c.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = c;
    cmd.CommandText = "select name from Employee1";
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(dr["name"].ToString());
         }
    }
 }
```

Comment: it is there `"if (!IsPostBack)"`

Answer (score 0):

bind your `DropDownList` as below

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    DataTable dt= new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select name, salary  from Employee1", conn);
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    DropDownList1.DataSource = dt
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "name";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "salary";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

then `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` give you the salary  of selected item, no need to initiate another database call.